# Writing to Google Persistent DIsk

Tags: java, disk, fileoutputstream

I've written some java code that creates a CSV file at the mount point of a disk I have attached to a Google Compute instance. I run the script in the form of a SQL stored procedure from the instance that the disk is attached to. The issue is that at the mount point, a "lost+found" folder is created where I would expect to find my CSV file. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time! The code is similar to as follows:

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileWriter;    
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 

public class file_write {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String filePath = "/mnt/point/file.csv"; 

        // Creates file in mount point 
        File myFile = new File(filePath);
        myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        myFile.createNewFile(); 
        
        FileWriter stringWriter = new FileWriter(myFile); 
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            stringWriter.write(i + ", ");
            stringWriter.write("something");
            stringWriter.write(System.lineSeparator()); 
        }
        
        stringWriter.close();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The directory **lost+found** is normal. Use regular file commands and make sure the mount point is working. What are you trying to accomplish with **myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();**? Your code should not try to create the mount point. That should be done before running your program.

Comment: The `myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()` is used to make sure that the directory I'm trying access exists. Without it, it says that my directory can't be found? The mount point is already created before then. What file commands are you referring to?

Comment: Please review what mounting a file system means. The directory must exist (called the mount point). Then a file system is attached to that directory. If you get an error that the directory does not exist, then you do not have a file system correctly mounted on that directory. 2) The command I referred to a normal file system commands such as **ls**, **cp**, etc.

Comment: Those commands work for me within the mount point. What might be other points of error?